# Extract the anomalies from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying explore the data I have, But I found lot of anamolies in my data. The date column of the dataframe has date like "12012-09-14" and "2500-09-28". I would like to replace them with "2250-05-05".

I would like to retain valid dates in df1 and those invalid dates into a list

df1:

```
col col2        date 
1   b1a2         NaN 
2   bal2  12012-09-14 
3   a3l2  12017-09-14 
4   a5l2  2019-09-24 
5   a8l2  2012-09-28 
6   a1l2  12113-09-14 
7   a0l2  12012-09-24 
8   a2l2  2500-09-28 
9   a6l2  2500-09-14 
10  a5l2  2012-09-24
```

Could someone help me how to extract those invalid dates?

Expected Output:

```
    col col2    date
0    1  b1a2 2250-05-05
1    2  bal2 2250-05-05
2    3  a3l2 2250-05-05
3    4  a5l2 2019-09-24
4    5  a8l2 2012-09-28
5    6  a1l2 2250-05-05
6    7  a0l2 2250-05-05
7    8  a2l2 2250-05-05
8    9  a6l2 2250-05-05
9   10  a5l2 2012-09-24
```

unique list of invalid dates:

```
invalid_list = ['12012-09-14','12017-09-14','12113-09-14','12012-09-24','2500-09-28']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill with the specified date:

```
new_date = pd.to_datetime("2250-05-05")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce').fillna(new_date)

    col col2    date
0    1  b1a2 2250-05-05
1    2  bal2 2250-05-05
2    3  a3l2 2250-05-05
3    4  a5l2 2019-09-24
4    5  a8l2 2012-09-28
5    6  a1l2 2250-05-05
6    7  a0l2 2250-05-05
7    8  a2l2 2250-05-05
8    9  a6l2 2250-05-05
9   10  a5l2 2012-09-24
```

---

**Update**

In order to get the invalid dates in a list:

```
to_dt = pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce')
invalid_list = df.loc[to_dt[to_dt.isna()].index, 'date'].dropna().values.tolist()
df['date'] = to_dt.fillna(new_date)

print(invalid_list)
['12012-09-14',
 '12017-09-14',
 '12113-09-14',
 '12012-09-24',
 '2500-09-28',
 '2500-09-14']
```

Comment: This is how the output should look, but I want to save those invalid dates to a list. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @yatu answers the first part of your question.

To get a list of the bad dates per the second part:

```
>>> df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').isnull(), 'date'].unique().tolist()
[nan,
 '12012-09-14',
 '12017-09-14',
 '12113-09-14',
 '12012-09-24',
 '2500-09-28',
 '2500-09-14']
```

Answer (score 2):

We can write a `regex` pattern for this to catch the faulty dates and then extract them with `boolean indexing` and `tolist`:

```
m = ~df['date'].str.match('(20\d{2}\-\d+\-\d+)', na=False)

df.loc[m, 'date'].tolist()
```

---

```
[nan,
 '12012-09-14',
 '12017-09-14',
 '12113-09-14',
 '12012-09-24',
 '2500-09-28',
 '2500-09-14']
```

**Note**: this doesn't generalize well to dates in 1900's:

Comment: you may want to consider valid dates in the 1900's.

Comment: I agree, just wanted to give a different solution than using `pd.to_datetime`. But fair point, added as **note**. @QuangHoang